# Cortana's auto reply

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, nokia-lumia-535, cortana, quiet-hours

I have set Cortana to reply in Quiet hours. She replies effectively, but not in the way I want. She simply forgets my name.

In Cortana's settings the message appears is "Hi, User5 is busy right now and may not respond right away" As in the following Screenshot.

[image]

but actually it replies "Hi, the person you're trying to reach is busy right now and may not respond right away" As in the following Screenshot.

[image]

I am tired of reminding my name to her but she always skips it down. Although she use to talk me with my name.

[image]
[image]

All settings are at their right place and all language region and speech settings are set to United States/English.

My phone is  dual sim Lumia 535 (RM-1090) running W10M (14393.693) if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

[Cortana](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17214/windows-10-what-is) has a default fixed auto-reply message to use during quiet hours:

[image]

The message cannot be changed (for now). That's why you have her sending generic replies

Check the [Cortana uservoice forum](https://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/258153-tasks-completion/suggestions/5874771-allow-editing-of-cortana-s-auto-reply-to-texts-dur), and see others who have requested the feature. Chances are its coming up in the next few builds of Windows 10 Mobile. Fingers Crossed ;)

Comment: But it appers in settings as  "Hi, User5 is busy right now and may not respond right away". Should I post an Screenshot of this?

Comment: I went into my own Quiet Hours Settings and tested it out, without cortana remembering my name. It brought the above response without my name in it...!!
Check under `Cortana's Notebook > About Me` and see what name is under there. Then tell me

Comment: I have updated my question. Have alook on it.

Comment: Hie @User5. I'm now forced to think its a bug. I've faced a similar issue. The most recent quiet hours reply excluded my name, of which when i check in the notebook, it shows u name..!! it must be a bug because after a few days, when i check Cortana, my name wont be showing. I will have to set it again

Comment: I don't have to set my name again and again. It is good for me that she don't forget my name as she behaves with you :D. Although she replies without my name :(.

Comment: @User5 lets hope Microsoft is going to fix it in the Creators Update

Comment: I have my fingers crossed but does not seem that it would be fixed so early unortunately :(.